# How to load bashrc in java program and execute command

Tags: java, linux, bash

```
public CGAOperationStatus downloadMetaData() {
        CGAOperationStatus retCgaOperationStatus = new CGAOperationStatus();
        try {
            createDirectoryIfNeeded("/sure/replication/metadata");
            String prepareRsyncCommand = "gsutil -m rsync -d -r gs://"
                    + storeCredentials.getStoreAccount()
                    + "/sure/metadata /sure/replication/metadata'";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(prepareRsyncCommand);
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception in downloading metadata from GoogleBucket");
            retCgaOperationStatus
                    .setScgaError(CGAError.SCGA_EXCEPTION_OCCURRED);
            ExceptionHandler.logException(logger, e);
            retCgaOperationStatus.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
        return retCgaOperationStatus;
    }
```

I have installed and Gcloud SDK on linux machine and i am trying to run gsutil command from a **Jar File** and my jar is executed from some outside program **over ssh** . But it just not working.

If i am running same command manually it works fine. May be because .bashrc is loaded when i am running command.

How can i do same thing from java.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a String[] instead of a simple String as a parameter in the call to Runtime.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gsutil", "-m", "rsync", "-d", "-r", "gs://"+ storeCredentials.getStoreAccount(), "/sure/metadata /sure/replication/metadata'"});
```

Comment: Not working, i did some changes as blow Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gsutil", "-m", "rsync", "-d", "-r", "gs://"+ storeCredentials.getStoreAccount() + "/sure/metadata" ,"/sure/replication/metadata"}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it's a python programm. You should insert "python" as first entry into your array: `new String[]{"python", "gsutil",...`

Comment: "Still not working". Can you share little bit more detail like an error message or something like that? Currently I'm short of crystal balls and oujia boards...

Comment: Yes, It did work after using full path of gsutil as /usr/bin/gsutil.